# How do we prove that the 4-acceleration transforms as a 4-vector in Special Relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, vectors, inertial-frames

In order to define the acceleration of a body in its own frame, we need to first prove that the acceleration is a four-vector so that its dot product with itself can then be labeled as acceleration squared in the rest frame. For velocity and displacement vectors, we can show that they have a constant dot product. But how do we prove that for acceleration?

Comment: Normally it's **defined** as a 4 vector.  What alternative definition are you using?

Comment: Are position and velocity 4 vectors in SR?

Comment: @WillO thank you for your comment. I meant that, for velocity four vectors, I can show that their dot product is a constant, but we don’t do the same for acceleration, so do we just assume that it satisfies as well?.

Comment: First, we must distinguish between what is a **constant** and what is an **invariant**. A scalar quantity having a specific value in all space points of an (inertial here) reference frame is a constant. A scalar quantity having the same value in all (inertial here) reference frames is an invariant. So you have proved that $\:(\mathbf{v\cdot v})\:$ is an invariant, more exactly it's $\:c^2\:$ in all inertial frames.

Comment: Yes I meant invariant. For a•a in the rest frame, we can say that it’s an invariant, but how do we know that a•a in some other frame will equal this?.

Comment: If the value of $a \cdot a$ is different some other frame, then it's not an invariant.  An invariant is the same in all frames by its very definition.

Comment: @Shaashaank you can take the dot product of acceleration four-vector with itself and prove that it's a Lorentz invariant for yourself, no need to accept or define it. One usually doesn't show this explicitly in textbooks because it is assumed that is clear to the student that the norm of every four-vector by virtue of its construction is a Lorentz invariant, and also because an explicit proof is tedious to perform.

Answer (score 4):

Is it not so by definition?
$$
{\bf a}= \frac {d{\bf v}}{d\tau}
$$
where
$$
{\bf v}= \frac{d{\bf x}}{d \tau}
$$
is a 4-vector and $\tau$ is a scalar.

Comment: Thank you for answering, for velocity, I can prove that the dot product of velocity with itself is a constant, how do we show that for acceleration?.

Comment: @Shaashaank : First, we must distinguish between what is a **constant** and what is an **invariant**. A scalar quantity having a specific value in all space points of an (inertial here) reference frame is a constant. A scalar quantity having the same value in all (inertial here) reference frames is an invariant. So you have proved that $(\mathbf{v\cdot v})$ is an invariant, more exactly it's $\:c^2\:$ in all inertial frames.

Comment: @Shaashaank : But if you have proved this it's not difficult to prove that $(\mathbf{a\cdot a})$ is an invariant following the same footing (replace $\mathbf x,\mathbf v$ with $\mathbf v,\mathbf a$ respectively).

Comment: @Shaashaank : As a hint $(\mathbf{a\cdot a})=-\Vert \boldsymbol\alpha_0\Vert^2=\text{invariant}$, where $\:\boldsymbol\alpha_0\: $ is the acceleration 3-vector with respect to the rest frame of  a particle.

Comment: @Shaashaank : Because of your low reputation you could not vote any post, answer  or question. But you can accept an answer to your question as best giving +15 reputation to the answerer. Try to learn how. And by the way, Welcome to PSE.

Answer (score 1):

Since you accept that four-velocity is a four-vector, this is an argument that four-acceleration is a four-vector:

$$a^{\mu}=\lim _{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{v^{\mu}(\tau+h)-v^{\mu}(\tau)}{h}$$.

The path is parametrized by $\tau$, the proper time, which is a scalar because it's equal to the spacetime interval (upto maybe a sign)

You can imagine carrying out this limit calculation in two different frames. If you're doing a numerical calculation, you will take $h$ to a small finite number.

The numerator will be a difference of four-vectors, hence it is a four-vector. The denominator is a scalar. Hence, the fraction is a four-vector.

This isn't a proof of course. A proof will try to argue that the limit of the sequence four-vectors, as $h\rightarrow 0$, will also be a four-vector (which makes sense sort-of)

**EDIT** Ok so, let's say $v^{\mu}(h)$ is a sequence of four-vectors paramerized by a real parameter $h$. Let $v^{\nu} (h)=\Lambda v^{\mu}(h)$, $\Lambda$ is a Lorentz transform.
Then,

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}v^{\nu} (h)= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\Lambda v^{\mu}(h)$$

$$=\Lambda \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} v^{\mu}(h)$$

So you see, the limit in one frame is the Lorentz transform of the limit in another frame (We could pull $\Lambda$ out of the limit because it's a constant matrix)

Answer (score -3):

In physics, we prove things with experiments. Four-vectors are components of a *mathematical model*. Does that model pass experimental test? Yes, in many cases. We use it because it passes those tests, not because of any mathematical proof.

Comment: The 4-accelaration is defined and by its definition is a priori 4-Lorentz vector, see @mike stone's answer, not proved by experimental tests.

Comment: @Frobenius But if that definition did not lead to results confirmed by experiment, we would reject it as irrelevant to physics.

Comment: In mechanics I define the following named "stupid 3-dimensional momentium"
$$\mathbf{s3m}=m^2\upsilon\,\mathbf n$$
What is the meaning of the "experimental test" of my definition ???
Note that I don't mention for what purpose I will use this 3-dimensional quantity.

Comment: @Frobenius thank you for replying, I meant that, for four velocity, we can show that it’s dot product is a constant, but for acceleration do we just assume it?.

Comment: @Frobenius Every test of relativity versus Newtonian mechanics is a test of the physical utility of your definition.

Comment: @Frobenius If you don't connect your definition to physical reality, it is pure mathematics.

Comment: What do you mean by "constant", as @Frobeneius says, ${\bf a}\cdot {\bf a}$ is an "invariant" , meaning independent of reference frame, but is not a "constant" as (unlike ${\bf v}\cdot {\bf v}=-c^2$)  it can vary with with $\tau$.

Comment: @mike stone ...Thanks for your important note : indeed, $\mathrm d(\mathbf{v\cdot v})/\mathrm d\tau=\mathrm d c^2/\mathrm d\tau=0$ but $\mathrm d(\mathbf{a\cdot a})/\mathrm d\tau=\mathrm d(-\Vert \boldsymbol\alpha_0\Vert^2)/\mathrm d\tau=-2\boldsymbol\alpha_0\cdot\mathrm d\boldsymbol\alpha_0/\mathrm d\tau \ne 0$ in general, where $\:\boldsymbol\alpha_0(\tau)\:$ is the acceleration 3-vector with respect to the rest frame of a particle.